# Systematically store output of conda list into python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, conda

I am trying to systematically store a given servers conda dependencies in a python dictionary for internal version control.

I cannot gain any head wind in trying to convert the output of conda list `type(string)` in python3.6 running in conda gpu environment on Linux OS.

```
conda list >

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu
absl-py                   0.4.1                    py35_0
aiohttp                   3.4.2            py35h7b6447c_0
apipkg                    1.5                      py35_0
astor                     0.7.1                    py35_0
async-timeout             3.0.0                    py35_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
```

Then from the python script I have tried:

```
conda_list_output = os.popen('conda list').read()
conda_list_output = {conda_list_output}
conda_list_output = eval(conda_list_output)
conda_list_output =pd.DataFrame([conda_list_command], columns['asdf']) #Thought since 4 columns, might be easier to convert to a df right away.
```

I am relatively new with working with `os.popen` and I do not know if this is the best path forward. Additionally I do not know how to grab any 1 single column by any linux filters, `grep`, `cut`, etc.

If you have any idea on a path forward, thank you in advance!

Comment: Pandas is way overkill and `eval` isn't necessary.  Loop over the output line by line, split on whitespace to get each column's value, populate a dictionary

Comment: Conda has a programmatic API that you can use, so you don't have to parse the string output from the CLI commands. See: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/api/index.html

Comment: please accept the answer if it helps with or solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
import conda.cli.python_api as Conda
import re

output = Conda.run_command(Conda.Commands.LIST)
# output is a tuple, also containing the exitcode
data = output[0].split("\n")

# define extraction method:
def get_words(line): return re.findall("[^\s]+",line)

# skip header row, andfinal line termination
words = [get_words(x) for x in data[3:-1]
keys, vals = [w[0] for w in words], [w[1] for w in words]
result = dict(zip(keys,vals))
```

this should very close to what you want.